# How to access user objects at the front end using Framework's TokenAuthentication

Tags: reactjs, django

How to access user objects at the front end using Django Framework's TokenAuthentication? I was able to successfully get a token, which includes the user id and username of the user logged in but I am unsure of how to get the rest of the user information in the front end.

I am a beginner in programing, so your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. There are too many ways to do that - or simply you can retrieve user info from user model by using user_id and return it as a json in response context.

```
from rest_framework import response, status

def user_info(request)
    user_ins = User.objects.get(id=request.user.id)
    context = {
                "user_info": {
                    "first_name": user_ins.first_name,
                    "last_name": user_ins.last_name,
                    "username": user_ins.username,
                    "email": user_ins.email
          }
    return response.Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK, data=context)
```